# How can I delete files in Python

Tags: python

I have several *.dbf files in a folder. Their names are of 8 digits such as 00043232.dbf, 00458283.dbf, 32349999.dbf, 83721092.dbf, 12139999.dbf, 48729999.dbf, ...

I want to delete files that end with 9999. So, in this case, I want to erase 32349999.dbf, 12139999.dbf, 48729999.dbf.

I can I do that in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would be to us glob.glob to find the relevant files, and then use os.unlink() on it:

```
import glob
import os

for file_path in glob.glob('*9999.dbf'):
    os.unlink(file_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html), [`os.unlink()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.unlink)